# How to check nginx server perfomance

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, dedicated-server

comrades!

I want to know if there is any way to determine and compare my dedicated server perfomance.
It is used as web server with nginx+php-fpm.

I live in Europe but server is located in US. I can test site speed in "tools pingdom" or ping it from different locations, but those are very subjectively and rough marks. And I cannot check how it works from here because the distance affects the site load speed.

Maybe some nginx benchmark emulating huge load like hundreds of users clicking on site? Better if it would be not just numbers, but the comparative chart showing where is my server on some scale between for example basic core i3 and top notch xeon.

The reason I need this is my site looking for me low performing. I should check everything to find the reason. Server has i5 and 16gb ram, so I guess the problem is in low bandwitch/or nginx config/ or server config itself/ or wordpress config.

Somewhere there is a bottleneck, I need advice on how to find in.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the free account gets you, but I have used [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) before and once you install their agents on your servers you get a lot of data. You can drill down into the application requests to get how much time php and mysql is taking.

I have also used jMeter before but found it a bit of a pain to set up. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NLeq-QxkSw) video might give you some help if you want to try it. Once the setup was complete it was pretty good.

Alternatively, you can use the [Apache Benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) tool. You don't have to be running Apache web server to use it. [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-performance-benchmarks-a-web-server.html) is a good write up on how to use it. Unfortuantly this won't give you charts.

Excerpt:

*For example if you want to send 10 request, type following command:

```
$ ab -n 10 -c 2 http://www.somewhere.com/
```

Where:

- -n 1000: ab will send 1000 number of requests to server http://www.somewhere.com/ in order to perform for the benchmarking session
- -c 5 : 5 is concurrency number i.e. ab will send 5 number of multiple requests to perform at a time to server 202.54.200.1*

If you are concerned about your database performance on the server(s) I would use this pearl script [here](http://mysqltuner.com/). It will read your mySQL settings and give you a report of what to change.